# Bootstrap 3 vs Bootstrap 4 font rendering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I`ve been struggling with this issue for a while now, even my co-workers can't figure this out.

The live version of this app runs on Bootstrap 3 and my local version on Bootstrap 4, the HTML is exactly the same. The font on Bootstrap 4 looks so much blurry than Bootstrap 3. I`ve tried all kinds of font rendering styling, but none solved the problem.

[Bootstrap 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiX3L.png)

[Bootstrap 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJpky.png)

You require a good pair of eyes to see the difference, but believe me, the difference is visible. Screenshots were made on the same screen.

Anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] and tell us which browser / operating system combinations this problem occurs on (and which you've tested without reproducing the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 uses the system UI font.

Reference: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/19098/commits/73e5e89e0efb938072ba3b1da5d06d0d0e659db9.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/19098

You might want to change back to the regular one if you think it's blurry.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to check for all the browsers (maybe it's just a browser thing)
2. Also you need to check your own css. However, have a look here: https://www.icondeposit.com/blog:how-to-properly-smooth-font-using-css3

Comment: This works for browsers other than Chrome, for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be only happening in Chrome. I guess I`ll have to deal with it. Thanks all!